# What are the countries restricted for Workings as a TB diagnosed individual?

Tags: bacteria, different-national-health, tuberculosis, geography, health-policy

I came across some shocking information that GCC countries and Brunei doesn't give work visa for person who was diagnosed by TB in past. Any spots in chest will be enough evidence to cancel the application for work visa.

Is there any other countries that follow same policies? Does scars in chest is harmful for individual?